# How can I access a machine's static IP remotely through wifi

Tags: networking, static-ip, remote-control

I have a machine that can be controlled by a PC through ethernet connection. The network settings on the machine are as follows,

IP: 192.168.1.240
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1

Once the ethernet connection is established, I can just enter the machine IP into the web browser and access the control page.

I have no issues connecting my Windows 10 laptop to the machine and pulling up the web interface. However, I would like to connect to the machine remotely through wifi. I've attached an ethernet-to-wifi dongle from IOGear and I can see the dongle connected to the wifi router and has the same IP as the machine. When I access the IP remotely from my web browser, I can no longer pull up the control interface and the browser tells me either the connection timed out or cannot connect.

The router IP is 10.88.111.254 and most other devices are on 10.88.111.x

How would I be able to fix this? Happy to provide more information.

Comment: Is the laptop on Windows?

Comment: Yes, laptop is on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you ping the machine from your laptop? Can you set the machine's IP address to auto(dhcp), or a static one on the 10.88.111.x network?

Comment: wifi or Ethernet is not the issue. You seem to have two separate networks, on two separate private IP ranges, but you haven't told us how they are connected. If your 192.* network is routed off the 10.* network through a NAT router, you will need port forwarding.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I can ping the machine in command prompt via ping 192.168.1.240 and it works fine. When I generate an Auto IPv4, it gives a 169.1xx.x.x IP (forgot the specific IP). The laptop I am using also does not have wifi capabilities.

Comment: @Paul The machine is set to 192.* and if I flash the network settings to become 10.* even the ethernet connection disappears. You are correct that both IPs are private IP ranges where one IP is reserved by the machine and DHCP assigned licenses via the router. How can I get these two to communicate?

Comment: If you can ping the machine while it's connected to the wifi router, then the issue may be with the web application? Can you add some details about the machine, like could you run commands on it locally to verify the webservice is still up? e.g. `curl http://192.168.1.240`

Comment: are you sure you don't have Client/AP Isolation enabled on the Wifi? that would explain at least some of this knot, especially since it appears you are not familliar with whatever configuration is routing traffic back and forth between the two networks.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Because this laptop doesn't have network capabilities, I am purely communicating to the machine via ethernet through the IPv4 protocol. I am able to connect to the 192.* IP address in my web browser when the ethernet port is plugged in.